# Capture INPUT value in raw html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, is this possible?

I have this html page:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form1").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var html = replaceAll($('html')[0].outerHTML, "<", "&lt;")
                html = replaceAll(html, ">", "&gt;");
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<hr />" + html;
            });
        });

        function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
            return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
        }

        function escapeRegExp(string) {
            return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Enter text here:
            <input type="text" id="TextBox1" />
            <p>
                Press enter to capture HTML.
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

This page simply captures the current html after a post and then displays it for viewing. Hence the replace statements that change < and > into < and > . The point of this page is to capture the current HTML.

And when I enter "Yabadabdoo!" in the text box and press enter, I get the following result in the html:

`<input id="TextBox1" type="text">`

But what I wanted to get was:

`<input id="TextBox1" type="text" value="Yabadabadoo!" />`

Am I doing something wrong, or can JQuery/Javascript even capture values from INPUTS?

Comment: looking at the source doesn't tell you what the current value is, only what the initial value is, and looking at the HTML in the console tells you what the value attribute is, not what the value property is, and it's the value property that is important, and that's what you want, not the attribute.

Comment: What I want is the html tag with a value attribute, just as I illustrated above. Doing this in C# and catching it inside the Render method gives me the desired results, but doing similar in JQuery/Javascript gives me the other results. We don't necessarily want to capture this in C#; client side scripting is more desirable. Hence my question, can it be done as requested in JQuery/Javascript?

Comment: `$('#TextBox1').val()` gives you the entered value, I have no idea why you're getting the entire HTML as a string and replacing parts of it ?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer: That html page simply grabs the html after a post and displays it. I'm replacing things like < and > with &lt; and &gt; so that the resulting html can be seen, instead of being re-rendered.

Comment: Then wrap the HTML in a `pre` tag etc. instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have the input value in the html string, you have to capture the `value-property` of the input-element and then set its `value-attribute` to that value.

To do this insert in your `submit-callback` after `event.preventDefault()`:

```
var inp = $("input"); inp.attr('value', inp.val());
```